# What is the Correct Way to Execute a CompletionStage in a Handle Block?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I'm executing a CompletionStage that might return an exception - it's attempting to insert a record into a database. If I get a "duplicate record" exception, I want to instead retrieve the already-existing record.

Here is my code:

```
MyObj obj = new MyObj();
obj.setUserId(userId);
obj.setEventId(eventId);

return database.insert(obj).handle((s, t) -> {
    if(t != null) { //TODO: check exception type
        CompletionStage<MyObj> recover = database.get(userId, eventId).thenApply(opt -> opt.get());
        try {
            return recover.toCompletableFuture().get();
        }
        catch(Exception e) { //TODO: check specific exception types
            throw new CompletionException(e);
        }
    }
    else {
        return obj;
    }
});
```

This seems to work, but I think it looks pretty messy. I'd ideally like to do this:

```
MyObj obj = new MyObj();
obj.setUserId(userId);
obj.setEventId(eventId);

return database.insert(obj).handle((s, t) -> {
    if(t != null) { //TODO: check exception type
        return database.get(userId, eventId).thenApply(opt -> opt.get());
    }
    else {
        return obj;
    }
});
```

The "handle" syntax won't allow me to just return a CompletionStage/CompletableFuture directly here. So, I need to use the kind of messy try/catch with "toCompletableFuture().get()".

I'm not incredibly familiar with the CompletionStage/CompletableFuture syntax. Is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: @DidierL, I think you are right - I saw that question earlier, but didn't recognize it as this same problem. I was able to use the top answer in that question to improve the code marginally. Though, as that other question mentions, the syntax is still not ideal.

Comment: If you want a better syntax, give a try to [EA Async](https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-async/), it simplifies the code a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
return database.insert(obj)
    .exceptionally (exception -> database.get(userId, eventId).thenApply(opt -> opt.get()));
```

You can use `exceptionally` to get this thing done. If an exception is thrown a `Function` is executed and the result is given to the subsequent tasks, otherwise this is transparent.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do this, I get a compiler error: "no instances of type variables U exist so that CompletionStage<U> conforms to MyObj".

I think the problem is that database.get returns a CompletionStage<MyObj>, but the "exceptionally" expects me to return a MyObj directly? If I just return "new MyObj()", that works.